# Is there an existing license similar to MIT that requires the original copyrightholder to be informed of public release of derivative work?

Tags: license

Is there a license that is basically an MIT license (public domain plus attribution) but in addition also requires someone who releases a derivative work publicly to inform the copyright holder of the release and granting the copyright holder the right to add a mention of the derivative work in a public list of derivative works?

Comment: A requirement to notify anyone would be way out of open source. It fails the desert island test.

Answer (score 3):

The requirement to inform the copyright holder of new releases of forks is a requirement that disqualifies a license from being open-source.

Such a license fails the [Desert Island Test](https://wiki.debian.org/DesertIslandTest), which effectively ensures that people who are not able to communicate back also get the freedoms of the license.

The right to mention a derived work in a public list is not something that can be controlled effectively in a copyright license. Copyright does not forbid you to compile such a list, so a statement around that topic in a copyright license has no meaning.

What you *can* do is to add a section to your documentation with the .list of derived works and ask your users to send you updates for that list when new derivative works are created and/or when new releases are published. You just can't make it a requirement.

Comment: How would it disqualify it from being open-source? Open source is not the same as free software (free as in freedom).

Comment: Or is your point that i can‘t ask questions for code with open source on on opensource.stackexchange if the license requires some form of royalty (in this case, i forming the copyright holder)? If so, which stackexchange would be apropriate for this question?

Comment: @user1282931, open-source is indeed freedom, but that freedom has to extend to everybody and not just the group of people that would be able to get a message to you. The "contact me" part is what makes the license not an open-source license. If you really want to have a license with that requirement, you will have to ask a lawyer to draft you a custom license.

Comment: @user1282931 on this site, [we use](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) the OSI's definition of *open source*, which would bar software that fails the Desert Island Test just as the FSF's four freedoms do.

Comment: @MadHatter so which stackexchange site is suited for this question then?

Comment: If you guys are so nit-picky here, you should probably rename this from opensource.stackexchange to free-software.stackexchange or fsf.stackexchange. Personally I feel such a license would grant me much more ‚freedom‘ than a GPL for example.

Comment: @user1282931 and yet OSI, which is what is being invoked here, stands for *Open Source Initiative*, and their definition of "open source" is widely used in practice, such as by various Linux distributions when deciding what can be included in their repositories.